# How to export data from an ancient SQL Anywhere?

Tags: export, sqlanywhere

I'm tasked with exporting data from an old application that is using SQL Anywhere, apparently version 5, maybe 5.6. I never worked with this database before so I'm not sure where to start here. Does anybody have a hint?

I'd like to export it in more or less any text representation that then I can work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up exporting the data by using isql and these commands (where #{table} is each of the tables, a list I built manually):

```
SELECT * FROM #{table};
OUTPUT TO "C:\export\#{table}.csv" FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ',' QUOTE '"' ALL;
SELECT * FROM #{table};
OUTPUT TO "C:\export\#{table}.txt" FORMAT TEXT;
```

I used the CVS to import the data itself and the txt to pick up the name of the fields (only parsing the first line). The txt can become rather huge if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Is there any possibility to export all tables at once ? Including CREATE TABLE statements for ex.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read http://www.lansa.com/support/tips/t0220.htm

Comment: I found other tutorials mentioning going into isql and running commands, but how do I connect to the database? where's the file for example?

Comment: If it's like v8 install it should be a .db file which you can connect to with ODBC assuming you're on windows.    Not trying to be coy - I use sybase on windows and aix

Comment: This is windows but I think it's version 5.

Comment: Open Data Sources from Control Panel and I think you should see it as a System DSN.  Configure should give you the sybase server name - start the service. Then in a command prompt try                        isql -U dba -P sql    though you'll probably need to add the service.  isql -h should give you the syntax

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just asked a similar question a few minutes ago regarding ASA 6.0.2 and this helps.